# Create .PEM key using openssl

Tags: openssl

I have public key, and I want to create **.PEM key** using this public key. I am using openssl tool.

I didn't tried any steps. Could you please suggest any steps to be followed to create .PEM key?

Answer (score 0):

try this one :
`openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048`
where private key is the name of the file and 2048 is the length of the private key ( install openssl with home-brew on Mac )!